# Return json with data from three tables in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.3

```
//CartController
$itens = CartItem::where('id_cart', $cart->id)->with('product')->get();
return response()->json($itens);
```

This code returns a JSON with the data of the cart item and the relative product. But I also want to return the images of the product, which is in the **ProductImages** table.

In my model **CartItem.php** I have

```
 public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id_product');
}
```

In my model **Product.php** I have

```
  public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductImages', 'id_product');
}
```

But, if I do

```
 $itens = CartItem::where('id_cart', $carrinho->id)->with('product')->with('image')->get();
```

I get the error

> Call to undefined relationship [images] on model [App\CartItem]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try it as:

```
CartItem::where('id_cart', $carrinho->id)->with('product.images')->get();
```

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 2):

You should load two tables by using `with()`:

```
CartItem::where('id_cart', $cart->id)
        ->with('product', 'product.images')
        ->get();
```

You can read an explanation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (see Nested Eager Loading section).

Answer (score 2):

you should make use of the nested eager load function:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

`$itens = CartItem::where('id_cart', $carrinho->id)->with('product','images')->get();`